# AngularJS $routeChangeSuccess callback arguments

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm new to AngularJS and am confused by the documentation regarding event listeners.

The documentation lists the following for the [`$routeChangeSuccess`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) event:

> $routeChangeSuccess Broadcasted after a route dependencies are
>   resolved. ngView listens for the directive to instantiate the
>   controller and render the view.
>
> Type:
>
> broadcast Target:
>
> root scope

However, no where does it reference any arguments that are passed to the callback function.  And yet, most of the examples I've seen here on SO all have a similar callback function listing:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, next, current) {
   ...
});
```

According to the AngularJS docs, all callbacks have the first argument as the `event`.  I get that.  But where are `next` and `current` coming from?  Where is that listed in any of the documentation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was documented in version less than 1.2 see this [**old documentation**](https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ng.$route). But it seems they haven't noticed that the callback signatures for their `broadcast` events are missing. On the other hand, if you don't mind reading from their github repository you can check this [**line here**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L407) for the `$routeChangeSuccess` callback parameters.

Update:
For the `Route` object you can actually refer to the $route properties [**documented here**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L239).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.  I was getting frustrated trying to understand how some of the snippets I read were working.

Comment: Looking at both the JS source doc and the 1.2 docs, they both refer to the `{Route}` object.  But I can't find the references to that either - only for the $route service.  Am I not looking in the right places?

Comment: Forgive my being obtuse, but what is "The `locals` contain the resolved values of the `resolve` map." supposed to mean?  I realize I'm new to Angular and all, but these API docs are making learning the blocks nearly impossible.  How am I supposed to know/understand what fields/functions I have accessible from the $route object?

Comment: you can check the `$routeProvider` provider https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider regarding what a `resolve` means and other objects that may relate to the documentation I have provided above. Note: The `when()` method accepts a route definition as the second parameter