# How to get requested route in angular when otherwise was used

Tags: angularjs, routes

I trying to determine what the original route was when angular defaulted to the `.otherwise` route.

I can't see any information in the documentation on this.

Now I am considering creating a service that intercepts the broadcast for route change start and storing that value.  But this seems overkill for something so simple.

So is there a better way to determine this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$routeChangeSuccess` event and get the previous route in one of the callback parameters of this event.

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/zC8K1fn76UKonkpFYA8V?p=preview)**

e.g.

```
  app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
      if(previous && previous.$$route) {
        console.log(previous.$$route); // displays previous route
      }
    });
  });
```

As a reference regarding its documentation, you can see this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939006/angularjs-routechangesuccess-callback-arguments/24940082#24940082)** I've answered.

Comment: I will give this a try I have been moved onto another urgent matter but will validate soon.